# React - native - fetch is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-native

[This is my error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Xsc.png)

Hello, i m having problem fetching my JSON data from PHP script. It was all working fine but when i added app.js routes condition and so on it has stopped working and returning with this error. (Before Signup and login was working - now none of them but i didnt edit any of the code for fetching data from PHP) dont u know where could be that problem?

```
export default class Login extends Component<> {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userEmail: '',
        userPassword: ''
    }
}
userLogin = () => {
    //  alert('ok');
    const {userEmail} = this.state;
    const {userPassword} = this.state;


    fetch('https://link', {
        method: 'post',
        header: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: userEmail,
            password: userPassword,
        })

    }).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
        alert(responseJson);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
signup(){
    Actions.signup();
}
render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Logo/>
            <TextInput onChangeText = {userEmail => this.setState({userEmail})} style={styles.inputBox} underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' placeholder="Email" placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff"/>
            <TextInput onChangeText = {userPassword => this.setState({userPassword})} style={styles.inputBox} underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' placeholder="Heslo" placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff" secureTextEntry={true} />

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.userLogin()}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.signupTextCont}>
                <Text style={styles.signupText}>No account</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.signup}><Text style={styles.signupButton}>Register</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
    </View>
    )
}
```

this is my code for login where this error occurs when i click on Login.

Comment: That's weird I tried your code and it's working https://snack.expo.io/SyeZj2K_f  which routes conditions are you refereing to?

Comment: Sorry, error was in the App.js (entry file) where i was using state = self - after deleting everything was fine.